# Magento 2. How to get path to sales email in code?

Tags: magento2, order-email

I got the following two pieces of code:

```
$bccEmail = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/email');

->addBcc($bccEmail)
```

The meaning is to send a bcc to the email that is stored on 'Send Order Copy To: '  in Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails -> Order -> Send Order Email Copy To:

Still I do not receive any bcc. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your `$bccEmail` to

```
$bccEmail = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('sales_email/order/copy_to', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

Comment: It worked this time! :D